# My printer does not support postscript?

Tags: java, printing

DocFlavor of my printer returned

```
image/gif
image/gif
image/gif
image/jpeg
image/jpeg
image/jpeg
image/png
image/png
image/png
application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref
application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref
application/octet-stream
application/octet-stream
application/octet-stream
```

Does this mean that my printer doesnot support postscript?

so what should i use here

```
DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
```

for printing any kind of document and providing specifications also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Postscript support as revealed by your doc flavor supported formats. Possible options are to convert your document to an image or render it in an HTML editor like [Jeditor Pane](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html) before printing.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that your printer doesn't support Postscript which also mean that you cannot use POSTSCRIPT Docflavor. You can see if you can find a library like [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to convert your document to postscript.